# "Nicht ohne Grund wird unser ausgezeichneter Support in den Bewertungen oft erwähnt"

Tags: translation, german-to-english

Wie würde man diesen Satz übersetzen? Ich würde spontan

> There is a reason why our outstanding support is often mentioned in the ratings

wählen, aber irgendwas stört mich an dem Satz. Wäre die Übersetzung korrekt?

Comment: Gehört nach "English.SE". Das, was Dich interessiert, sind doch Englische Nuancen.

Comment: @userunknown: Why EL&U? Translations from English to German and German to English are on-topic here. We have the tags, as you've probably noticed.

Comment: [Are translation requests from German allowed? / Sind Fragen nach Übersetzungen aus dem Deutschen erlaubt?](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/136/are-translation-requests-from-german-allowed-sind-fragen-nach-bersetzungen).

Comment: @Gigili: Read Roberts http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/a/152/266 answer - he is obviously talking about the finer points of the German language. This question here is for experts of the English language - no matter how they decided about translations, that's not our beer.

Comment: Den Deutschen Satz kann ich mir hervorragend unter einem Cartoon in der Titanic vorstellen. Im realen Leben sagt man besser "Nicht ohne Grund wird unser Support in den Bewertungen lobend erwähnt"

Comment: Ich habe auch überlegt, ob diese Frage in EL&U besser aufgehoben ist als hier. Aber die Frage kann nur von Leuten beantwortet werden, die -- auch -- gut genug deutsch können, um Nuancen im Deutschen zu verstehen. Die findet man nun mal hier eher als auf EL&U.

Comment: @elena Ich sehe das immer andersrum. Vllt verstehen Muttersprachler den Satz besser, aber die sind nicht in der Lage einen guten englischen Satz zu formulieren. Während *a native (english) speaker* den deutschen Satz erst interpretieren muss, dann aber einen hervorragende Übersetzung machen kann (jaja, es gibt Leute, die beherrschen die eigene Sprache nicht; lassen wir hier bitte außen vor). Wenn ich von de->en übersetze, überlege ich welches von 20 Wörter das hier treffende ist. Bsp: Warum outstanding und nicht excellent? Kann man outstanding im Bezug zu Support doppeldeutig verstehen? etc.

Comment: @userunknown Laut http://english.stackexchange.com/faq#questions sind Übersetzungen auf [english.se] per Definition off topic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is a reason why our outstanding support is often mentioned in the ratings

Das klingt, als wolltest Du gleich noch den Grund nennen. Vielleicht liegt's am "why". Denn eigentlich willst Du ja nicht auf den Grund selber eingehen, sondern nur betonen, dass der Support so ausgezeichnet ist, dass er in den Bewertungen genannt wird.

Was hältst Du von:

> There is a reason that our outstanding support is often mentioned in the ratings. *(edited to include Gigili's suggestion)*

… ohne "why"?

Comment: I think you should add "that" to your second sentence. "There is a reason that our outstanding support is often mentioned in the ratings."

Comment: Good point, that sounds even better.

Answer (score 1):

Hier noch ein paar Variationen:

Für eine Bewertung des Unternehmens:

> For good reasons **business valuations** often refer to our outstanding support.
>   It is not without reason that our excellent support is often mentioned in **company assessments**.

Für eine Bewertung der Software:

> **Reviews** often note our outstanding support for good reasons.
>   There are good reasons why **evaluations** often highlight our excellent support.

Comment: *It is not without reason* ... sagt man sowas im englischen? Das klingt nach einer Wort-für-Wort Übersetzung ;p

Comment: @Em1: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+without+reason&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3